# How can I print ALL my json nested data in the end of each "father" line in python?

Tags: python, json, parsing

```
import json


with open('json.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)


for event in data['input']:
    edition = event.get('edition', '')
    name = event['name']
    start_date = event['startDate']
    end_date = event.get('endDate', '')

    for location in event['location']:
        city= location.get('city', '')
        state= location.get('state', '')
        country= location.get('country', '')
    
    
    print(edition,name,start_date,end_date,city,state,country)


---
{
    "input": [
        {
            "edition": "4th",
            "name": "JBCN Conference",
            "startDate": "2018-06-11",
            "endDate": "2018-06-13",
            "location": [
                {
                    "city": "Barcelona",
                    "country": "Spain"
                }
            ]
 },
 {
     "edition": "3rd",
     "name": "DevTernity",
     "startDate": "2018-11-30",
     "endDate": "2018-12-01",
     "location": [
         {
             "city": "Riga",
             "country": "Latvia"
         }
     ]
 },
 {
     "edition": "1st",
     "name": "I T.A.K.E Unconference",
     "startDate": "2016-05-19",
     "endDate": "2016-05-20",
     "location": [
         {
             "city": "Bucharest",
             "country": "Romania"
         },
         {
             "city": "Maramures",
             "country": "Romania"
         }
     ]
 },
 {
     "edition": "2nd",
     "name": "Product Owner Rule Book",
     "startDate": "2016-04-11",
     "endDate": "2016-04-13",
     "location": [
         {
             "city": "Paris",
             "country": "France"
         },
         {
             "city": "Madrid",
             "country": "Spain"
         }
     ]
 },
 {
     "name": "Upfront Summit",
     "startDate": "2018-02-01",
     "location": [
         {
             "city": "Los Angeles",
             "state": "California",
             "country": "United States"
         }
     ]
 },
 {
     "name": "IBM Think",
     "startDate": "2018-03-19",
     "location": [
       {
             "state": "Nevada",
             "country": "United States"
       }
     ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I only get the last nested item for city,state,country, BUT I want to print all the cities, states and countries of each event in the same line.

Current Output:

- 4th JBCN Conference 2018-06-11 2018-06-13 Barcelona  Spain
- 3rd DevTernity 2018-11-30 2018-12-01 Riga  Latvia
- 1st I T.A.K.E Unconference 2016-05-19 2016-05-20 Maramures  Romania
- 2nd Product Owner Rule Book 2016-04-11 2016-04-13 Madrid  Spain
- Upfront Summit 2018-02-01  Los Angeles California United States
- IBM Think 2018-03-19   Nevada United States

Desired Output:

- 4th JBCN Conference · 2018-06-11 / 2018-06-13 · Barcelona, Spain
- 3rd DevTernity · 2018-11-30 / 2018-12-01 · Riga, Latvia
- 1st I T.A.K.E Unconference · 2016-05-19 / 2016-05-20 · Bucharest | Maramures, Romania
- 2nd Product Owner Rule Book · 2016-04-11 / 2016-04-13 · Paris, France | Madrid, Spain
- Upfront Summit · 2018-02-01 · Los Angeles, California. United States
- IBM Think · 2018-03-19 · Nevada, United States

Comment: What is the problem. your output and desired output are same

Comment: @n-ata it is not, look at the 1st and 2nd event, the location i get is the last one

Comment: Could you place your json object here.

Comment: @n-ata i have added the Json under the code

Answer (score 0):

Because in your location there is more than one location.
That is why city, state, country gets last one.
Look you set `city = firstCity` and then you set `city = secondCity`. Here your location `for loop` sets last value to variables. And you print it outside of location loop.
just print it in location loop or do something similar to my code.

```
for event in data['input']:
    edition = event.get('edition', '')
    name = event['name']
    start_date = event['startDate']
    end_date = event.get('endDate', '')
    loc = ''
    for location in event['location']:
        city = location.get('city', '')
        state = location.get('state', '')
        country = location.get('country', '')
        if city:
            loc += city
        if state:
            loc += ' | ' + state
        if country:
            loc += ' | ' + country
        if location != event['location'][-1]:
            loc += ', '

    print(edition, name, start_date, end_date, loc)
```

and here is output:

```
4th JBCN Conference 2018-06-11 2018-06-13 Barcelona | Spain
3rd DevTernity 2018-11-30 2018-12-01 Riga | Latvia
1st I T.A.K.E Unconference 2016-05-19 2016-05-20 Bucharest | Romania, Maramures | Romania
2nd Product Owner Rule Book 2016-04-11 2016-04-13 Paris | France, Madrid | Spain
 Upfront Summit 2018-02-01  Los Angeles | California | United States
 IBM Think 2018-03-19   | Nevada | United States
```

Here if you print inside of location loop:

```
for event in data['input']:
    edition = event.get('edition', '')
    name = event['name']
    start_date = event['startDate']
    end_date = event.get('endDate', '')
    for location in event['location']:
        city = location.get('city', '')
        state = location.get('state', '')
        country = location.get('country', '')

        print(edition, name, start_date, end_date, city, state, country)
```

your output would be:

```
4th JBCN Conference 2018-06-11 2018-06-13 Barcelona  Spain
3rd DevTernity 2018-11-30 2018-12-01 Riga  Latvia
1st I T.A.K.E Unconference 2016-05-19 2016-05-20 Bucharest  Romania
1st I T.A.K.E Unconference 2016-05-19 2016-05-20 Maramures  Romania
2nd Product Owner Rule Book 2016-04-11 2016-04-13 Paris  France
2nd Product Owner Rule Book 2016-04-11 2016-04-13 Madrid  Spain
 Upfront Summit 2018-02-01  Los Angeles California United States
 IBM Think 2018-03-19   Nevada United States
```

if you don't want to repeat printed locations. Just do something similar to my first example

Comment: Yes it works! Now I undertand the error, is it possible in the "1st I T.A.K.E Unconference" event to show the country only once as it is repeated?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

EDIT - BTW, your problem is you are reassigning variables with each iteration of city and country, you need to add them to the variable eg city += " " + location.get('city', '')

```
from json import loads as json_loads
from re import sub as re_sub

data = json_loads(open('json.json').read())


for event in data['input']: 
    output = " · ".join([i for i in event.values() if type(i) != list])
    for location in event['location']:
        output += " · " + ", ".join([i for i in location.values()])
    output = re_sub(r"(\d) · (\d)", r"\1 / \2", output)
    print(output)
```

output:

```
4th · JBCN Conference · 2018-06-11 / 2018-06-13 · Barcelona, Spain
3rd · DevTernity · 2018-11-30 / 2018-12-01 · Riga, Latvia
1st · I T.A.K.E Unconference · 2016-05-19 / 2016-05-20 · Bucharest, Romania · Maramures, Romania
2nd · Product Owner Rule Book · 2016-04-11 / 2016-04-13 · Paris, France · Madrid, Spain
Upfront Summit · 2018-02-01 · Los Angeles, California, United States
IBM Think · 2018-03-19 · Nevada, United States
```

UPDATE: ok, that gave me a bit of a headache, but I think its good now, should be more reliable now too, the previous version would fail if dictionary keys were out of order in the json file.

```
from json import loads as json_loads
from re import sub as re_sub

data = json_loads(open("json.json", "rt").read())

order = ["edition", "name", "startDate", "endDate"]

for line in data["input"]:
    output = ""
    location_dict = {}
    locations = line.pop('location')
    output += " · ".join([line[property] for property in order if property in line])
    location_dict.update({location['country']: f" | ".join([", ".join([city.get('city', ""),
     city.get("state", "")]).strip(", ") for city in locations if city['country'] == location['country']])
      for location in locations})
    output += " · " + " · ".join([f"{city[1]}, {city[0]}" for city in location_dict.items()])
    output = re_sub(r"(\d) · (\d)", r"\1 / \2", output)
    print(output)
```

Output:

```
4th · JBCN Conference · 2018-06-11 / 2018-06-13 · Barcelona, Spain
3rd · DevTernity · 2018-11-30 / 2018-12-01 · Riga, Latvia
1st · I T.A.K.E Unconference · 2016-05-19 / 2016-05-20 · Bucharest | Maramures, Romania
2nd · Product Owner Rule Book · 2016-04-11 / 2016-04-13 · Paris, France · Madrid, Spain
Upfront Summit · 2018-02-01 · Los Angeles, California, United States
IBM Think · 2018-03-19 · Nevada, United States
```

Comment: This almost perfect, is it possible to show Bucharest | Maramures, Romania instead of romania 2 times?

Comment: Updated it sorry if its confusing.

Comment: Thats amazing! I will try to understand everything :)